How to handle FALSE boolean values on Cloud page in Marketing Cloud?
We are implementing a cloud page that will act as a subscriber center. We have created this code:
%%[
If RequestParameter("submitted") == "SaveChanges" then
    /* Get the checkbox value from the Newsletter */
    SET @NewsletterChecked = RequestParameter("Newsletter")
    /* Determine the value to update based on whether checkbox is checked or not */
    IF IsNull(@NewsletterChecked) THEN
        /* Checkbox is unchecked, set the field to false */
        SET @NewsletterValue = "false"
    ELSE
        /* Checkbox is checked, set the field to true */
        SET @NewsletterValue = "true"
    ENDIF
    /* Get the checkbox value from the NewsletterSweden */
    SET @NewsletterSwedenChecked = RequestParameter("NewsletterSweden")
    /* Determine the value to update based on whether checkbox is checked or not */
    IF IsNull(@NewsletterSwedenChecked) THEN
        /* Checkbox is unchecked, set the field to false */
        SET @NewsletterSwedenValue = "false"
    ELSE
        /* Checkbox is checked, set the field to true */
        SET @NewsletterSwedenValue = "true"
    ENDIF
    /* Update the Salesforce Contact field with the new value */
    SET @updateStatus = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(
        "Contact", @skey,
        "Ourcheckbox_1__c", @NewsletterValue,
        "Ourcheckbox_2__c", @NewsletterSwedenValue
    )
         Redirect('http://google.com/')
ENDIF
]%% 

When we update the checkboxes to TRUE in salesforce it is then displayed as TRUE on the Cloud Page so that works fine, but the issue for us is when we set the checkboxes to FALSE it is not updated on the cloud page... what are we doing wrong?

That's because when you uncheck the checkbox, the value of @NewsletterChecked is set to False, not null.
The below ISNULL condition fails when the checkbox is 'unchecked'.
IF IsNull(@NewsletterChecked) THEN
....

Instead, try with
IF @NewsletterChecked =='false' THEN
....

